# Reduce one for loop to decrease time complexity

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using NumPy to find out langrage polynomial interpolation. I'm using 2 for loop to find out langrage polynomial, but I want to reduce 2nd for loop so that my code time complexity can be less. Can you guys please suggest me how I can cut a for loop to increase my time complexity.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class LagrangePolynomial:
    def __init__(self, data_x, data_y):

        assert type(data_x) == np.ndarray, "data_x is not numpy array"
        assert type(data_y) == np.ndarray, "data_y is not numpy array"
        assert len(data_x) == len(data_y), "length of data_x and data_y must be equal"

        self.x = data_x
        self.y = data_y

        self.degree = len(data_x) - 1


    def __str__(self):
        strL = f"LagrangePolynomial of order {self.degree}\n"
        strL += "p(x) = "
        count=0
        for i in self.y:
            if i == 0:
                continue
            elif i >= 0:
                strL += f"+ {i}*l_{count + 1}(x) "
            else:
                strL += f"- {-i}*l_{count + 1}(x) "
            count+=1
        return strL
    def __call__(self,x):
        y_interp = np.zeros(len(x))
        for i in range(len(x)):
            #remove this for loop.
            for j in range(self.degree + 1):
               upper=np.prod(np.delete(self.x - x[i],j))
               lower=np.prod(np.delete(self.x[j] - self.x, j))
               y_interp[i] +=(upper/lower)*self.y[j]
        return y_interp
data_x = np.array([-3.,-2.,-1.,0.,1.,3.,4.])
data_y = np.array([-60.,-80.,6.,1.,45.,30.,16.])

p = LagrangePolynomial(data_x, data_y)

#generating 100 points from -3 to 4 in order to create a smooth line
x = np.linspace(-3, 4, 100)
print(p)
y_interp = p(x)
plt.plot(x, y_interp, 'g--')
plt.plot(data_x, data_y, 'ro')
plt.legend(['interpolated', 'node points'], loc = 'lower right')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Lagrange Polynomial')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The second loop can be eliminated by creating a 2D array by tiling the `self.x` array with the `np.tile` method. The removal of elements in de 1D array with `np.delete` can than be replaced with a *boolean mask* (unfortunately this results in a 1D array which needs to be reshaped).

The calculation of the 2D array can be done outside the first loop, as can be the calculation of `lower` as they do not depend on `x`.

See my rewrite of the `__call__` method:

```
def __call__(self,x):

    y_interp = np.zeros(len(x))
    
    n = self.degree + 1
    mask =  ~np.eye(n, dtype=np.bool)

    tiled = np.tile(self.x, (n,1))
    masked = np.reshape(tiled[mask], (n, n-1))

    lower = np.prod(self.x[:,np.newaxis] - masked, axis=1)
    
    for i in range(len(x)):

        upper = np.prod(masked -x[i], axis=1)
        
        y_interp[i] = np.sum((upper/lower) * self.y)
           
    return y_interp
```